# QGIS- Creating a python program to customize a login page for users of QGIS

Tags: pyqgis

Is there any method to create a customized login page for users to open QGIS desktop wherein the user activity can be tracked?
Once a user clicks on the QGIS desktop icon, the alert box shows login id and password and once the users gives the credentials . they can easily login to their particular project

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  We're a little different from other sites. We're a Q&A site, not a discussion forum.  For questions that involve code we ask that you show us where you are stuck with your own code by including a [code snippet](http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/4312) in your question.  There is an [edit] button beneath your question which will enable you to do that and a **`{}`** button that enables you to format any highlighted code nicely.  Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works. Thanks.